# Excel VBA - Copy a Column without Header without Selecting

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to clean up my VBA code to not `.select` anything anymore if I don't have to (nor use `.Activate`) because that seems to be the cardinal rule of efficient VBA coding. Here is my problem, I want to copy the contents of Column K on one sheet to an area on another sheet (same workbook) without the header and I am having a time figuring out how to reference that range.

I figured out how to count the number of cells when I have a filter on for another area of the project (`shReport.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1`), but this sheet doesn't have a filter and I'm not counting the cells; I am copying and pasting them and then removing the duplicates, thus creating a reference list. Also, everything I see with `.End(xlDown)` online seems to be with `.Selection`.

How do I turn this terribly inefficient code into proper coding?

```
Sheets("LAS Report").Select
Range("K2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Calc").Range("B19").Paste
Range("B19").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods that apply to your `Selection` also apply directly to a `Range`

You can directly copy ranges without selecting them:

```
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LAS Report")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc") 'define after sheet is created

ws1.Range("K2", ws1.Range("K2").End(xlDown)).Copy _
  ws2.Range("B19")
```

And remove duplicates:

```
ws2.Range("B19", ws2.Range("B19").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: This worked when the LAS Report sheet was selected, but when I run a longer code and it has the Calc sheet open (because it just created it), it copies nothing. If I take just this code in a test sub, I get a Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error. If I step into the code and select the LAS Report sheet before the copy line, then it works and pastes to the Calc sheet without it being selected.

Comment: @Jordan Try and change `Range("K2").End(xlDown)` to `Worksheets("LAS Report").Range("K2").End(xlDown)`. When you're not already on the correct sheet, you need to validate all the ranges. I'll edit my answer